# Understanding execution context inside object literal

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

I am very new to javascript programming, i am trying to understand how javascript program works. Hence i read about concepts like execution context, execution stacks etc. After understanding a bit of execution context i learned that **"this"** refers to execution context.
So i tried to print execution context inside an object literal to check the execution context, hence i wrote the following code.

```
var obj = {
    method: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
};
obj.method();
```

This gives me an output as:

> { method: [Function: method] }

After seeing this i have two questions, that is, is the above code correct to know the execution context?, and if yes, then shouldn't execution context should be an **Object { method: function() }** instead of the output it is giving.

I tried reading a lot regarding this but i couldn't crack it.

Comment: `this` (in this case) refers to the object that the method was called on (`obj`). The exact style of console output depends on your browser but `{ method: [Function: method] }` is the same thing as `Object { method: function() }`.

Comment: there's no difference in what you are expecting and what you got as context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome the output looks like

```
{method: ƒ}
```

Internet Explorer

```
[object Object]   {}
```

Firefox

```
Object { method: method() }
```

They all mean the same thing and refer to the object `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually right.

`this` refers to the environment in which the JavaScript code is executed.

And you are also right about it being an object in your particular case.

```js
var obj = {
  method: function() {
      console.log(typeof this);
  }
};
obj.method();
```

Run the snippet above, you will find the type of `this` as object.

That basically means that your environment (`this`) is an object, which contains a property called `method` which is a function.

There is much more to `this` than this.